# How to automatically create imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview

My android project connected to server.And i retrieve data from server if it's 5 then create 5 imageview in linearlayout in other words automatically create imageview, depends on retrieved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code Loops over number of images and creates new ImageView for each time, and then it adds them to the Parent Linear Layout. You can also set the LayoutParams of ImageView dynamically as well.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
for(int i=0;i<number_of_images;i++) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    layout.addView(image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks how do i add into Horizontal view

Comment: It depends on your parent Layout. If you parent layout's orientation is `android:orientation="horizontal"` then it will add the childs horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Linear Layout:

LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
                 linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                 linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
for(int i=0;i<Number_Images;i++){
//ImageView Setup
ImageView i mageView = new ImageView(this);
//setting image resource
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
//setting image position
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//adding view to layout
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
}
//make visible to program


setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Hope this Help You.